# Show hide div and script based on radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm trying to implement validation into my form being conditional. Basically if the user selects email radio option then email is going to be required, or if phone is selected then phone field would be required.

So far I've gotten this code to work, form submits and validation works fine. But if I switch to phone, then switch back to email, the validation is loaded so form won't submit if I haven't filled out both fields.

I have it set that way but basically trying to make it so if one field is selected then the other required. Any better ways to do this?

HTML:

```
<label>Method of Contact</label>
<label class="radio">
    <input type="radio" name="group" value="ck1" checked/>
    Email
</label><br />
<label class="radio"><input type="radio" name="group" value="ck2" />
    Phone
</label>
<div id="emaildisp">
    <label>Email</label> 
    <input id="emailv" name="email" type="email" />
</div>
<div id="phonedisp"> 
    <label>Phone</label> 
    <input id="phonev" name="phone" type="text" />
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
$(function()
{
    if (jQuery('input[value=ck2]:checked').length > 0)
    {
        jQuery('#phonedisp').show();
        jQuery('#emaildisp').hide();
        jQuery("#phonev").validate(
        {
            expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
            message: "Please enter your phone number"
        });  
    }
    else 
    {
        jQuery('#phonedisp').hide();
        jQuery('#emaildisp').show();
        jQuery("#emailv").validate(
        {
            expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
            message: "Please enter your email"
        }); 
    }

    jQuery('input[name=group]').change(function() 
    {
        var selected = jQuery(this).val();console.log(selected);
        if(selected == 'ck2')
        {
            jQuery('#phonedisp').show();
            jQuery('#emaildisp').hide();
            jQuery("#phonev").validate(
            {
                expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
                message: "Please enter your phone number"
            });  
        } 
        else 
        {
            jQuery('#phonedisp').hide();
            jQuery('#emaildisp').show();
            jQuery("#emailv").validate(
            {
                expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
                message: "Please enter your email"
            }); 
        }
    }); 
});
```

**Solution:**
Thanks to the answers below, I came up with the solution. Key difference, I was not using jquery validation plugin, rather a different validation script. So I switched over, for beginners, just look it up you'll simply have to add link to the script in the header.

Next I gave the form an id, #myform. Then I have the ck1 and ck2 radio button their own respective ids, #ck1id and #ck2id. And using the below code, if the radio button is selected, then depending on the id selected, next part becomes validation required.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>     
$(function(){
jQuery('input[name=group]').change(function() {
  var selected = jQuery(this).val();console.log(selected);
  if(selected == 'ck2'){
    jQuery('#phonedisp').show();
    jQuery('#emaildisp').hide();
    } else {
   jQuery('#phonedisp').hide();
   jQuery('#emaildisp').show();
  }
 }); 
jQuery('input[name=group]').triggerHandler('change');
});
</script>

<script>
$(function(){
    // validate signup form on keyup and submit
    $("#myform").validate({
        rules: {
            group: "required",
            email: 
                {
                    required: '#ck1id:checked',
                    email: true
                },
            phone: 
                {
                    required: '#ck2id:checked',
                    digits: true
                }
        },
        messages: {
            group: "Please select one",
            email: "Please enter your email.",
            phone: "Please enter your phone."
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.rules("remove")` to remove jquery validation.

```
$(function(){
jQuery('input[name=group]').change(function() {
  var selected = jQuery(this).val();console.log(selected);
  if(selected == 'ck2'){
    jQuery('#phonedisp').show();
    jQuery('#emaildisp').hide();
    jQuery("#emailv").rules("remove"); //remove the other field validation
    jQuery("#phonev").validate({
    expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
    message: "Please enter your phone number"
    });  
  } else {
   jQuery('#phonedisp').hide();
   jQuery('#emaildisp').show();
   jQuery("#phonev").rules("remove"); //remove the other field validation
   jQuery("#emailv").validate({
   expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
   message: "Please enter your email"
   });  
  }
 }); 
jQuery('input[name=group]').triggerHandler("change");
});
```

I see that you have duplicated code, just remove it and use `jQuery('input[name=group]').triggerHandler("change");` to trigger it when page first loads

Comment: Thank you so much for a cleaned up code! Toggling between the phone and email works beautifully. Just one issue however, the validation remove doesn't seem to work, I get an error saying "object has no method 'rules'". Once I remove the rules line it works perfectly, except when I toggle between the radio buttons it'll have me fill in both fields. Thanks again!

Comment: @Jake: it seems that you're using a library other than jquery validation plugin. The idea is to remove the other field validation. Check the documentation of the library you're using to find the relevant method. Hope you find it.

Comment: That indeed was the problem, I was using the plugin by GeekTantra, turned out not to be too efficient. So switched over to jquery validation plugin. Thanks a lot for the help again, I'll update the post so if someone else falls into the same situation they can see.

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the previously added validation from the other fields those are not required. If you need phone remove validation from email and vice versa.

You can follow two way, either remove validation or ignore the validation.

```
1. Removing the validation:

    jQuery("#emailv").rules('remove');

            or 

    jQuery("#phonev").rules('remove');

2. Ignore validation:

    jQuery("#emailv").validate({
       ignore: "#emailv"
    });

            or

    jQuery("#phonev").validate({
       ignore: "#phonev"
    });
```

Check if this helps you.

Comment: Thanks! Though ignore or rules doesn't seem to work when switching back and forth between the radio buttons, rules results a 'object has no method' error in console and ignore for some reason doesn't effect it.

Comment: Jake i forget to include your ids for ignore case, rectified it, please try now and let me know, mean while let me go through the "object has no method" error.